# Directed/indirected graph memory management?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, properties

For example I have classes Edge and Node:

```
@interface Node

@property ... NSArray *edges;

@end


@interface Edge

@property ... Node *nodeFrom;
@property ... Node *nodeTo;

@end
```

How should I define these properties - assign/retain? Because if I define them as assign ones then they potentially could release their memory too early. But if I define them as retain ones then they could be closely connected, because they retain each other.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you want garbage collection.

Comment: The only idea I have is to define all the properties with `assign` and to store somewhere a retained array of all these objects.

Comment: `edges` should be retained as it is the array itself that you need to keep around (inserted objects will be retained by the array). I would also retain `nodeFrom/To`. declare a `dispose` method that release your retained properties when you no longer need an object.

Comment: If your graph has no loops, you can make nodeFrom a weak reference and the problem is solved. But an undirected graph has loops on each undirected edge, and that's where gc comes in. Any solution you write will boil down to your own implementation of gc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set it up like this, so nodes own their edges:

```
@interface Node

@property (strong) NSArray *edges;

@end


@interface Edge

@property (weak) Node *nodeFrom;
@property (weak) Node *nodeTo;

@end
```

This way, edges will be deallocated when both of their nodes are deallocated.

There is [no built-in way to notify the edges that a node has deallocated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19344940/1445366), so you could end up with an Edge with only one Node.

There are two solutions for this:

1. Check to see if `nodeFrom` and `nodeTo` are both set before relying on this edge.
2. In `-[Node dealloc]`, iterate through the `edges` array and inform the edges that this node will deallocate.  The edge can then send a message to the other node that it's no longer a valid edge, and the other node can deallocate the invalid edge.

On a side note, `NSSet` may be a better candidate for `edges` than `NSArray`, since edges are unordered.

Comment: But this would lose any node which is not referenced by something other than an edge

Comment: I'm assuming that all nodes are owned by something like a `Graph` class with a set of `nodes`. (This could be updated in `-[Node dealloc]` as well.)  How else would you find any Nodes unless you already had a reference to one?

Comment: By following the edges. In my experience, graphs like this usually have a few links to the rest of the program, and are left to manage themselves otherwise (they are traversed as information is needed)

Comment: I think this answer is enough for me. It is better than iterating through the whole graph (and maybe multiple times)